# Finding nearest value within a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, matching

I'm trying to finding the nearest value for each treated observations. The data look as follows (a partial data from 1.2M obs):

```
> dta
     id treatment      score
 1:   5         0 0.02381024
 2:  10         0 0.05428605
 3:  22         0 0.02118124
 4:  27         0 0.01495214
 5:  45         0 0.01877916
 6:  50         0 0.02120360
 7:  58         0 0.02207263
 8:  60         0 0.02807019
 9:  61         0 0.05432927
10:  65         1 0.59612077
11:  68         0 0.02482168
12:  72         1 0.14582400
13:  73         0 0.02371670
14:  77         0 0.02608826
15:  87         0 0.06852409
16:  88         0 0.07473471
17:  94         0 0.07160314
18:  97         0 0.02040747
19: 104         1 0.09878789
20: 108         0 0.02421807
```

For each treated observations (i.e., treatment = 1) I'd like to get an untreated observation (i.e., treatment = 0) with the nearest score and mark the chosen observation as unavaiable for other treated observations to match.

For example, the first treated observation (row 10) will matched to id = 88 (row 16), row 12 to row 17, and so on. Currently I'm running the floowing loop:

```
smpl_treated = dta[treatment == 1]
smpl_untreated = dta[treatment == 0]

n_tmp = nrow(smpl_treated)
matched_id = matrix(0, n_tmp, 1)

smpl_tmp = smpl_untreated

for (i in 1:nrow(smpl_treated)) {

  x = smpl_treated[i]$score

  setkey(smpl_tmp, score)
  tmp = smpl_tmp[J(x), roll = "nearest"]
  matched_id[i] = tmp[[1]]
  smpl_tmp = smpl_tmp[id != tmp[[1]]]

}

matched_smpl = smpl_untreated[id %in% matched_id]

> matched_smpl
   id treatment      score
1: 87         0 0.06852409
2: 94         0 0.07160314
3: 88         0 0.07473471
```

Any suggestions to make this happen within a data.table or make the loop faster? With the original 1.2M obs the loop takes over 2 hours. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Suppose you have the following 5 samples: {(id = 1, treatment = 0, score = 0), (id = 2, treatment = 1, score = 0.1), (id = 3, treatment = 1, score = 0.2), (id = 4, treatment = 1, score = 0.3), (id = 5, treatment = 0, score = 0.4)}.  In other words, you have 3 treated observations wedged between two untreated observations.  In this case, what maps to what?

Comment: In my context, it won't happen. If it happens, however, probably I should do the opposite - the main purpose of this is getting a balanced sample of treated and untreated observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This elaborates [the already accepted answer of denis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46888383/3817004) using the *actual* possibilities of `data.table` syntax, e.g., use the `on` parameter instead of `setkey()` when joining.

```
# determine the minimum number of treated and untreated cases
n <- min(dta[treatment == 0L, .N], dta[treatment == 1L, .N])
# order by descending score 
mdt <- dta[order(-score)][
  # and pick the ids of the top n treated and untreated cases
  # so that the highest untreated score match the highest treated score,
  # the 2nd highest untreated the 2nd highest treated and so forth
  , .(id0 = head(.SD[treatment == 0L, id], n), id1 = head(.SD[treatment == 1L, id], n))]
mdt
```

> ```
>    id0 id1
> 1:  88  65
> 2:  94  72
> 3:  87 104
> ```

```
# join the ids two times to show the data of the treated and untreated cases
dta[dta[mdt, on = .(id==id0)], on = .(id = id1)]
```

> ```
>     id treatment      score i.id i.treatment    i.score
> 1:  65         1 0.59612077   88           0 0.07473471
> 2:  72         1 0.14582400   94           0 0.07160314
> 3: 104         1 0.09878789   87           0 0.06852409
> ```

Comment: This so solution is so much better than mine, and actually does the job (it doesn't suppose that the treatment and non treatment data have different score range). Thank you for sharing

Comment: @denis Thank you for your nice comment. However, your solution pointed into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I may have a solution if you order your data table, make a subset and use the power of merging.
Not sure it is the best solution, but it seems to work for what I understood you want to do, and it will be for sure faster than your loop:

```
library(data.table) 
dta <- data.table(id = c(5,10,22,27,45,50,58,60,61,65,68,72,73,77,87,88,94,97,104,108), 
                  treatment = c(0, 0  ,0  ,0,  0, 0, 0 ,0 , 0 ,  1, 0 ,1 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0),
                  score = c(0.02381024, 0.05428605, 0.02118124, 0.01495214, 0.01877916, 0.02120360,
                            0.02207263, 0.02807019, 0.05432927, 0.59612077, 0.02482168, 0.14582400,
                            0.02371670, 0.02608826, 0.06852409, 0.07473471, 0.07160314, 0.02040747,
                            0.09878789, 0.02421807))

setkey(dta, score) # order by score
treated_nbr <- dta[treatment == 1, .N] # just to simplify the next line

selecteddata <- 
  dta[treatment == 0, 
      .SD[(.N - treated_nbr + 1):.N,
          .(correspid = id, 
            correspscore = score, 
            id = dta[treatment == 1, id])]]
```

here we take the same number of ordered non treated person (`.N-treated_nbr+1):.N`) so that they have the closest score to the ordered one, and we merge the id to the id of the treated one (`id = dta[,.SD[treatment == 1,id]]`)

```
setkey(selecteddata, id)
setkey(dta, id)
selecteddata[dta] # do the merging
```

Not sure it is exactly what you want, because I realized it works only if your treated scores are higher than the not treated ones (which is the case in your example).
You could add a condition to use the solution proposed only for treated person with score higher than the non treated ones, and do the rest otherwise (I don't see a direct simple solution otherwise)